# Android отправка данных из Main Activity в Class и работа с ними

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

изучаю Android недавно, столкнулся с проблемой, не могу решить уже продолжительное время, помогите пожалуйста. Проблема состоит в этом: Есть MainActivity и переменные в нем, есть отдельно созданный класс, как грамотно передать данные из MainActivity в этот класс для хранения определенных данных? Intent не подходит, так как второй класс не является активностью, и startActivity инициализирует другую активность, поэтому в нужный класс данные не передает (null).

Код-попытка достать данные при помощи Intent:
**MainActivity**:

```
...
val name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
val sname = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPassword)

val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, DataClass::class.java)
val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("login", name.toString())
            bundle.putString("email", sname)
            bundle.putString("test", "hello world")
            myIntent.putExtra("MyPackage", bundle)

...
```

**DataClass.kt**:

```
class DataClass {

    val callerIntent = intent // <-- Error is here, 'Unresolved reference: intent'
    val packageFromCaller = callerIntent.getBundleExtra("MyPackage")
    val contact = packageFromCaller!!.getString("login")
    val email = packageFromCaller!!.getString("email")
    val test = packageFromCaller!!.getString("test")

}
```

Задавал такой вопрос на зарубежном Stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73303449/android-sending-data-to-class-from-mainactivity/73304512#73304512 ; однако полученный там ответ выдает ошибку `"Unresolved reference: intent"` в **DataClass.kt**

Comment: Вы что-то странное очень неправильно делаете. Опишите что и зачем вы хотите сделать - расскажем как это сделать. Пока что, судя по описанию и представленному коду, вам не нужно вообще использовать Intent таким образом и для таких целей. Скорее всего вам можно просто в конструктор данные передать. Но это не точно, т.к. неизвестна цель. А она определяет что и как надо делать.

Comment: Цель - использовать класс DataClass как хранилище данных. По мере развития программы потом реализовать retrofit-тело POST-запроса, используя переменные хранящиеся в этом классе. Передача в POST параметров введенных пользователем, их, соответственно нужно передать в этот класс из MainActivity, что у меня никак не выходит сделать

Comment: Кажется, вам будет достаточно чего-то такого: `data class UserInput(val email: String, val login: String)`. И данные в него передавать просто через конструктор: `UserInput("test@test.ru", "test")`. Главное - правильные данные передавать. Сейчас у вас в коде идёт попытка не введённое в поля ввода содержимое в переменные писать, а что-то другое. Скорее всего вы имели в виду что-то такое: `UserInput(name.getText().toString(), sname.getText().toString())`. При этом надо иметь в виду, что делать это надо только после ввода теста в поля ввода. по нажатию кнопки и/или в слушателе ввода текста.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь, попробую реализовать это у себя в проекте

Comment: Вы плохо понимаете интент, активность не причем, им можно передать данные и в класс и в сервис